# Using float:none for list instead of left

Tags: html, css

Is there any reason to use `float:left` instead of `float:none` in a list that I want to just have displayed normally? I ask because when I do `float:left`, the entire left nudges up a bit too much:

[image]

If I do `float:none`, it looks fine:

[image]

I'm curious if there is any other gotcha in using it though.

EDIT: Sorry, I've included an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/remkrupe/

Note: if I change ul to be display:inline instead of inline-block, it also behaves the way I want (but this interferes with something else in my code). But the example above you'll see the elements in the "what_i_want" class all lined up next to each other, while the other ones "jump up" (while still lined up with respect to each other).

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please?

Comment: Off topic (or maybe not): `ul` is a block-level element, and as such is invalid inside `span`.

Comment: Is it "ok" to put the ul in the span since I set its display to inline-block? The idea here is that I am essentially putting an inline list in a line of text. I'd like to keep the list semantics while having it flow in text.

Comment: It would be better to make the span a div. If you have to, set the div to `inline-block`.

Comment: `.not_what_i_want ul li
{
    display:inline-block;
}` remove `float: left;` and it works.

Comment: Ah great, thank you. If you place that as an answer I can mark it correct..

Answer (score 0):

you can leave `ul` elements as `display:block` you just need to pay attention to resetting `padding` and `margin` property

```
.want
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 display:block
 }
  .want>ul, .want li{
  margin:0; margin:0;
 }

.want ul li{
  float:left;
}
```

**[fiddle](http://sfiddle.net/maio/remkrupe/1/)** (in the fiddle check for `want` class)